# JS how to force user to click a link in a form

Tags: javascript

I have a html form with multiple form elements as well as a link inside the form that opens to a website.  I create a Javascript overall form validation to validate elements in the form as well as the link as I would want to enforce user to have to click on the link if not the form will not go through when user clicks submit button. Moreover, when user clicks on the button to submit info in the form but does not click on the link, I would want to remind user to click in the link. I create a modal drop down validation alert to remind user to click on the link but I struggle to find the JS validation logic to alert user to click on the link before click the submit button.  Any help is appreciated. Below is my JS code for validation.

```
//Approach 1 
function validation_modal(){
                    $(".form-modal").modal("show");
                }
    function validation_form(){   
                   $(document).off("click", "a", function() {
                        var href = $(this).attr("href");
                        if(href !== "https://www.../")  
                        {
                          $(".modalNote").text("Please click on the link");
                          validation_modal();
                          return false;
                        }
                    })
                    ...other elements in form validation
    }
// Approach 2
    function validation_modal(){
                    $(".form-modal").modal("show");
                }
    function validation form() {
                   $(document).on("click", "a", function() {
                        var href = $(this).attr("href");
                        if(href !== "https://www...")  
                        {
                          $(".modalNote").text("Please click on the link");
                          validation_modal();
                          return false;
                        }
                    })
            ...other elements in the form validation
    }
```

Both of my above logic has either not work and not achieve what I would want to do.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you add some HTML as well so we can test it ? And sorry to ask but why on earth would you want that ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the html code for the link in the form

```
<div class="row row-label c_5" id="sec5_div" "><br>
      <a href="https://...form.pdf" target="_blank"> Department Request Form </a>
</div><br>
```

This is a user request as the link opens to another form which has to be filled out and submit before the main form.